# Java SQL: Date subtract integer

Tags: java, date

I would explain my problem by example:

The current date is: 23/07/2015

The date I need is 21/07/2015

How can i subtract the current date to get the second one using `java.sql.Date`?

This is what I tried but it subtract the month as well..

```
Calendar calendar_One_Day_Before = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_One_Day_Before.setTime(endDate);

                int theDayBefore = calendar_One_Day_Before.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 2;
                String tdb = theDayBefore + "/" +calendar_One_Day_Before.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + year;
                System.out.println("the day before: " + theDayBefore);
                System.out.println("month of the day: " + calendar_One_Day_Before.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                System.out.println(tdb);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it subtract the month"?  You're not modifying the Calendar object at all.

Comment: the last `System.out.println` statement prints: 22/05/2015. While `theDayBefore` just take `DAY_OF_MOTH` and subtracted by 2, this statement doesn't perform any operation on moth but the output month still got modified

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

You can "subtract" time using Calendar.roll(), as in:

```
private Calendar twentyFourHoursAgo() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, false);
    return cal;
}
```